# How can I access detox element matchers in custom helpers?

Tags: react-native, detox

I am looking to access the `element` and `by` variables which are globally available in my test, but when I try to call them from a helper module required/imported by the test I get an undefined error. How can I import these variables directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `detox.init()` call happens earlier than you access those variables (`element`, `by`) because init method is the actual place where Detox globally exposes them.

After you call `await detox.init(<your options>`), you'll be able to initialize your helpers.